# Does paint flashpoint have any thing to do with drying time?

Tags: paint

I was looking at the specs for [Kilz original](http://www.kilz.com/products/primer/kilz-original) and saw it had a flashpoint of 75 degrees Fahrenheit. I didn't know what flashpoint was, so I found the following definition:

> Flammable liquids have a flash point of less than 100°F. Liquids with lower flash points ignite easier. Combustible liquids have a flashpoint at or above 100°F. The vapor burns, not the liquid itself. The rate at which a liquid produces flammable vapors depends upon its vapor pressure.

Source: https://blink.ucsd.edu/safety/research-lab/chemical/liquids/

It's interesting that the dry time for this paint is cited at 77 degrees Fahrenheit, two degrees higher than its flash point.

> Dry Time at 77°F (25°C), 50% RH
>   Dries to the touch in 30 minutes at 77°F (25°C) and 50% humidity.
>   Recoat or topcoat after 1 hour.

Does drying at a temperature over have any beneficial effect such as less fumes or improved drying time?

Comment: Your question suggests that you are thinking about raising the temperature as an intentional intervention. You have to be careful about that. I think that the paint is formulated to dry without heated forced air directed on it. Possibly this could cause the surface to skim over and inhibit drying of the interior of the paint layer. Primer is formulated to dry quickly at normal room temperatures  and without having an air current directed on it; personally I wouldn't try to speed up drying by heating or even forced air at 75 F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash-point only has an indirect relationship to drying or curing times. Generally , the warmer the curing temperature , the faster and stronger a resin cure will be.